# Auto Adjusting Date Ranges on Entry of a New Range in MS-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me out with the following scenarios in SQL

Scenario 1:

Consider I have a table with the following date range

```
FromDate    ToDate   

01-01-2018    1900-01-01
```

Now when I input a date range of 10-02-2018 to 25-04-2018

My desired output must be

```
FromDate    ToDate   

01-01-2018    10-02-2018
10-02-2018     25-04-2018
25-04-2018     1900-01-01
```

Scenario 2:

Consider I have a table with the following range

```
FromDate    ToDate   

01-01-2018    25-04-2018
25-04-2018    30-06-2018
30-06-2018    05-08-2018
```

Now when I give a new range 28-04-2018 to 11-7-2018

My desired output must be

```
FromDate    ToDate   

01-01-2018    25-04-2018
25-04-2018    28-04-2018  
28-04-2018    30-06-2018 
30-06-2018   11-07-2018 
11-07-2018    05-08-2018
```

Scenario 3:

Consider I have a table with the following range

```
FromDate    ToDate   

01-01-2018    25-04-2018
25-04-2018    30-06-2018
30-06-2018    05-08-2018
```

Now when I give a new range 15-07-2018 to 28-07-2018

My desired output must be

```
FromDate    ToDate   

01-01-2018    25-04-2018
25-04-2018    30-06-2018
15-07-2018    28-07-2018
```

Comment: Which server you are using, SQL server, MySQL or anything else?

Comment: Do you have any code so far? What are you trying to query? I assume you're trying to insert data for some purpose but any background would be good. What do you mean by "give a new range"?

Comment: Are you looking for a trigger to do this automatically or a stored proc?

Comment: It would be helpful it you gave a higher-level description of what this is supposed to accomplish. Aside from that it's also complicated because you seem to use '1900-01-01` as a infinity (on top of a different date format.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by modifying a little based on the given answer by **Paul**

```
    DECLARE @Range TABLE(
        FromDate dateTIME,
        ToDate dateTIME
    );

    DECLARE @FinalTable TABLE(
        FromDate dateTIME,
        ToDate dateTIME
    );

    DECLARE @MaxToDate DATETIME = 0

   INSERT INTO @Range
VALUES ('2018-01-01', '2018-04-25'),
    ('2018-04-25', '2018-06-30'),
    ('2018-04-28', '2018-07-11');


    WITH Boundaries
    AS (
        SELECT
            Boundary,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Boundary) AS rowNum
        FROM (
            SELECT FromDate AS Boundary
            FROM @Range     

            UNION

            SELECT ToDate AS Boundary
            FROM @Range     
        ) T
    )


    INSERT INTO @FinalTable
    SELECT A.FromDate, A.ToDate FROM (

    -- Select the first pair
    SELECT
        MIN(Boundary) AS FromDate, MAX(Boundary) AS ToDate
    FROM Boundaries
    WHERE rowNum IN (1, 2) and Boundary <> 0
    HAVING  MIN(Boundary) != MAX(Boundary)

    UNION

    SELECT A.Boundary AS FromDate, B.Boundary AS ToDate
     From Boundaries A 
     JOIN Boundaries B ON A.rowNum + 1 = B.rowNum
     WHERE A.Boundary != B.Boundary and A.Boundary <> 0 AND B.Boundary <> 0
    ) A


    SET @MaxToDate = (SELECT MAX(ToDate) FROM @FinalTable);

    IF(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @Range WHERE ToDate = 0) = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @MaxToDate = (SELECT  MAX(ToDate) FROM @FinalTable)

        IF @MaxToDate <> 0
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @FinalTable
            SELECT
            @MaxToDate,
            0
        END
    END

    SELECT * FROM @FinalTable
```

Comment: Glad you solved it. Note, a more conventional way of writing `IF(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @Range WHERE ToDate = 0) = 1` is `IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM @Range WHERE ToDate = 0)`.

It'd be etiquette to up-vote my answer, if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two parts to this:

1. A query to generate the distinct consecutive pairs of ranges;
2. A way of updating the table in the way you describe when new data is inserted.

Unless I have misunderstood your problem, I think the key to the first part is to realise that there is no difference in meaning between your `FromDate` and `ToDate` columns.

Assuming you can't change your table definition, you could generate your desired output with the following query (I've used a temporary table containing some test data for convenience):

```
CREATE TABLE #Range (
    FromDate date,
    ToDate date
);

INSERT INTO #Range
VALUES ('2018-01-01', '2018-04-25'),
    ('2018-04-25', '2018-06-30'),
    ('2018-04-28', '2018-07-11');

WITH Boundaries
AS (
    SELECT
        Boundary,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Boundary) AS rowNum
    FROM (
        SELECT FromDate AS Boundary
        FROM #Range

        UNION

        SELECT ToDate AS Boundary
        FROM #Range
    ) T
)
-- Select the first pair
SELECT
    MIN(Boundary), MAX(Boundary)
FROM Boundaries
WHERE rowNum IN (1, 2)

UNION

-- Select all subsequent pairs
SELECT
    MIN(Boundary), MAX(Boundary)
FROM Boundaries
WHERE rowNum > 1
GROUP BY rowNum / 2
HAVING MIN(Boundary) != MAX(Boundary);

DROP TABLE #Range;
```

The two queries at the end are needed because we need to use the second row twice.

The second part really needs more information about your circumstances to answer. The answer could well be to put the above logic in a view, so that the data in your base table can be left alone. If you are able to change the base table, it could be converted to a table containing a single column of dates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solved the issue by modifying the answer you suggessted me.